# Peut-on « être les yeux bleus » ?

Tags: grammaire, ellipse

In my textbook, a man is described like this: "Il est grand, mince, les yeux bleus.". Is it possible to *be* blue eyes ("être les yeux bleus")? I thought one should say "Il a les yeux bleus".

If it is correct, how would you translate this into English?

1. "He is tall, slim, with [or has] blue eyes." – Good written and spoken English.
2. "He is tall, slim, blue eyed." – Good english. *blue eyed* as an adjective.
3. "He is tall, slim, blue eyes" – Not very good written English, but in speech it could be ok as a way of listing different characteristics. *blue eyes* as a noun.

---

Dans mon livre de cours, un homme est décrit comme ça : « Il est grand, mince, les yeux bleus. ». Est-ce que c'est possible être les yeux bleus ? Je croyais qu'on disait « il a les yeux bleus ».

Si c'est correct, comment est-ce qu'on traduit la phrase en anglais ?

1. "He is tall, slim, with [or has] blue eyes." – Bon anglais à l'orale et l'écrite.
2. "He is tall, slim, blue eyed." – Bon anglais. Adj. *blue eyed*.
3. "He is tall, slim, blue eyes" – Mauvais anglais à l'écrite, mais à l'orale une énumération de qualitées. Nom *blue eyes*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete [@M42's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8913/2964) you can't say :

> Il est les yeux bleus.

It's a mistake.

But **if** there is other descriptive words before "yeux bleus" which accept the *être* verb, then the *avoir* verb can be omited although the correct sentence is "*avoir les yeux bleus*".

I don't think this is an official rule, but it's curent French.

---

En complément de la réponse de M42 et pour répondre clairement au titre de la question on ne doit pas dire :

> Il est les yeux bleus.

C'est une erreur plutôt grossière...

En revanche **si** il y a d'autres mots descriptifs avant l'expression "yeux bleus", et si ils fonctionnent avec le verbe *être*, alors on peut omettre le verbe *avoir* (qui devrait normalement être présent de cette manière : *avoir les yeux bleus*).

Je ne pense pas que ce soit une règle officielle, mais cela reste largement acceptable dans le français courant que je pratique quotidiennement.

Answer (score 4):

La phrase est correcte, l'auxiliaire avoir est omis. La phrase complète serait :

> Il est grand, mince avec les yeux bleus.
>
> Il est grand, mince et il a les yeux bleus.

In english it's the same:

> He is tall, slim, with [or has] blue eyes.

Comment: But is it ok to omit *avoir* in this case, in written language? Would you do that in a news article for example?

Comment: @citizen: Yes, for me it is ok to omit *avoir* even in an article because it is not ambiguous.

Comment: C'est correct car utilisé couramment ou correct car recommandé par l'Académie ou les deux à la fois ?

Answer (score 2):

C'est correct puisque le verbe "avoir" est sous-entendu dans ce contexte. La traduction anglaise de l'expression serait "tall, slim, blue-eyed" pour conserver la répétition des traits descriptifs. "with blue eyes" brise un peu l'effet en anglais.

Comment: "Il est grand, mince, [il a] les yeux bleus" est la phrase complète ; pour alléger la prosodie, on omet le deuxième verbe qui devient sous-entendu.

Answer (score 1):

(English follows.)

C'est sous-entendu mais c'est quand même douteux venant d'un livre. C'est plus courrant de dire « Il est grand, mince, aux yeux bleus… » Comme d'autres disent aussi, « avec les yeux bleus » serait utilisé oralement.

---

It is correct as it is implied, but coming from a text book it should say “Il est grand, mince, aux yeux bleus…” As others put it “avec les yeux bleus” would be the preferred way to say it, especially orally.

Comment: How can it be "aux"?

Comment: Because "au" can substitute "avec" in this situation. There are 2 eyes though, so you add an x.

Comment: Interesting @Mr Jack. Should this be understood as "*in* blue eyes", as you in English can say (at least I think, I'm not a native speaker) both "a man *in* a black suit" and "a man *with* a black suit" (both wearing it)?

Comment: That is a great comparison, couldn't have found a better example myself! (although "*in blue eyes*" sounds awkward)